# Java Generics and ClassCastException in Generalization

Tags: java, android, generics

It might not be related, but this is under Android 2.3.3 and I work with openjdk7.

I'm trying to compute the velocity and displacement of an object using its acceleration values, given coordinates in 3 spaces plus time.  For that, I created a class named `Coord4D`, and `Velocity`, `Displacement` and `Acceleration` are child of this class.  Like this:

`Coord4D`:

```
class Coord4D {

    // Statics //
    private static final long ONE_TO_NANO_FACTOR = 1000000000;

    // Members //
    private long key;
    private float xValue;
    private float yValue;
    private float zValue;

  // ... more ...
}
```

and an example of inheriting class `Velocity`:

```
public class Velocity extends Coord4D{

  // ... members and methods and stuff ...

}
```

And now the problem.  In `Coord4D`, I generalize the method to obtain an antiderivative from derivatives.  For instance, I want to retrieve a `Velocity` instance given two `Acceleration` instances (past and current) and the `Velocity` instance from a previous frame.

Everything was working fine when the methods to do this were in `Displacement` and `Velocity`, but I found it was redundant since both were computing the exact same things, and I hate writing two times the same lines of code.  So I decided to move these methods into `Coord4D`, and to use generics like this:

```
protected static <Derivative extends Coord4D, 
AntiDerivative extends Coord4D> AntiDerivative getIntegrationStep(
        Derivative previous, 
        Derivative current, 
        AntiDerivative previousStep){

    // Time is in nanoseconds, must change it in seconds
    float dT = ( current.getTime() - previous.getTime() ) 
            / ONE_TO_NANO_FACTOR;

    // Parameters have seconds for unit : ..., ?*s, ?, ?/s, ?/s², ... 
    float dX = current.getX() - previous.getX();
    float dY = current.getY() - previous.getY();
    float dZ = current.getZ() - previous.getZ();


    // do the integration step and add the previous step value
    float x = dX * dT + previousStep.getX();
    float y = dY * dT + previousStep.getY();
    float z = dZ * dT + previousStep.getZ();

    return (AntiDerivative) new Coord4D(current.getTime(), x, y, z);
}
```

and the `Velocity` and `Displacement` objects have this method (example from `Velocity`).

```
public static Velocity getVelocity(Acceleration previousAccel, 
        Acceleration currentAccel, 
        Velocity initialVelo) {

    return getIntegrationStep(previousAccel, 
            currentAccel, 
            initialVelo); 

}
```

Now, for some reason, this line

```
return getIntegrationStep(previousAccel, currentAccel, initialVelo);
```

result in a `ClassCastException`. I don't understand why, as I think my logic with the generics is fine.  Can someone help me finding where is the flaw?

The stack trace (from LogCat):

```
W/dalvikvm(8891): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d648)
E/AndroidRuntime(8891): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(8891): java.lang.ClassCastException: me.aybabt.android.prototypes.physics.Coord4D
E/AndroidRuntime(8891):     at me.aybabt.android.prototypes.physics.Velocity.getVelocity(Velocity.java:40)
E/AndroidRuntime(8891):     at me.aybabt.android.prototypes.AcceleratorActivity.onSensorChanged(AcceleratorActivity.java:199)
E/AndroidRuntime(8891):     at android.hardware.SensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SensorManager.java:539)
E/AndroidRuntime(8891):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(8891):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime(8891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
E/AndroidRuntime(8891):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(8891):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(8891):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
E/AndroidRuntime(8891):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
E/AndroidRuntime(8891):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: My guess would be build path issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
return (AntiDerivative) new Coord4D(current.getTime(), x, y, z);
```

can't work.

AntiDerivate is a subclass of Coord4D. You can't cast from a class to its subclass. (Only the other direction works.)

What you can do: Instead of using `new Coord4D` you get the class of previousStep, which is an instance of Antiderivate, and with Class.newInstance() you create the new instance which you want to return.

Comment: First thanks for your answer!  In my view of this, `AntiDerivative previousStep` is sent by `Velocity` as `Velocity initialVelo`, so `AntiDerivative` should resolve to `Velocity`.  Here `AntiDerivative` is the name of the generic, it could be seen as `T extends Coord4D` and I send `T` as being `Velocity` which extends `Coord4D`.  So I think the line you quoted should work.

Also, using reflection would work, but I need to do this manipulation many times a second, so I think the cost of reflection would show up and make my app sluggish.

Comment: What you write is correct, but with your `new` statement you create an instance of Coord4D and _not_ of Velocity. You can't cast Coord4D to Velocity. - If you want to avoid reflection, then as an alternative solution you can make the class Coord4D abstract, add there a method `newInstance(t, x, y, z)`, which has to be implemented by subclasses and which you call instead of the `new` statement.